# Mysql find rows with same id and date range

Tags: mysql, date, range, double

I'm trying to get the product_id, date and the total duplicates from a table. This table contains the id, product_id, price, wholesale_price, date_add and some more fields.
Currently there are over a million of rows with products added to lookup the price history of a product. But some products have double values with the product_id and the date.
For example:

| id_price_history | id_product | price | date_add |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 6.95 | 2021-11-15 12:12:15 |
| 2 | 1 | 6.95 | 2021-11-15 12:14:25 |
| 3 | 2 | 4.95 | 2021-11-16 10:18:45 |
| 4 | 2 | 4.95 | 2021-11-16 11:18:55 |
| 5 | 3 | 8.95 | 2021-12-15 14:12:15 |
| 6 | 1 | 7.95 | 2021-12-16 12:14:25 |
| 7 | 1 | 7.95 | 2021-12-16 12:14:25 |
| 8 | 1 | 7.95 | 2021-12-16 12:14:25 |
| 9 | 4 | 29.95 | 2021-12-16 14:12:16 |
| 10 | 5 | 12.50 | 2021-12-16 14:12:17 |
| 11 | 1 | 6.95 | 2021-12-17 14:12:20 |
| 12 | 2 | 5.95 | 2021-12-17 14:12:22 |

So what I would like to have as output:

| id_product | date | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-15 | 2 |
| 2 | 2021-11-16 | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-12-16 | 3 |

I have tried different things with GROUP BY, HAVING COUNT() like:

```
SELECT id_product, date_add, COUNT(*) as total FROM price_history
GROUP BY id_product HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT date_add) > 1;
```

Or:

```
SELECT ph.id_product, date_add, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM price_history ph
JOIN (SELECT id_product FROM price_history HAVING COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(date_add, '%Y-%m-%d')) > 1) b
ON ph.id_product = b.id_product LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you're trying to achieve: (though I kept price in the grouping)

```
SELECT id_product, price, date(date_add) AS 'date', count(*) AS total 
  FROM price_history
 GROUP BY id_product, price, date(date_add) HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

...which gives your desired output:

```
id_product  price   date        total
1           6.95    2021-11-15  2
2           4.95    2021-11-16  2
1           7.95    2021-12-16  3
```

Example [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=36bd7f39d575fb969ff6bab3b2cfb44d).

Comment: Thanks Paul! That did the job. Added a WHERE-clause because I got a timeout. But that's just because the huge amount of data in that table.